# R- current column minus sum of next x other columns till condition is met

Tags: r

I try to get the sum column done with R but it does not work.
Its actually simple to illustrate:
sum = points of current row - sum(bonus rows up till the first participation equals to 0) I would prefer a crisp and short code if it is possible.

```
Pupil   participation   bonus   points
  2           55          6       10
  2           33          3       10
  2           88          9       10
  2           44          8       10
  2           44          0       10
  2           66          7       10
  2            0          0       10
  1           22          11      10
  1           33          12      10
  1           33          13      10
  1            3          13      10
  1           44          1       10
  1            0          3       10
  1            0          0       10
```

to

```
Pupil   participation   bonus   points   sum
  2           55          6       10      10-(6+3+9+8+0+7)
  2           33          3       10      10-(3+9+8+0+7)
  2           88          9       10      10-(9+8+0+7)
  2           44          8       10      10-(8+0+7)
  2           44          0       10      10-(0+7)
  2           66          7       10      10-(7)
  2            0          0       0        0
  1           22          11      10      10-(11+12+13+13+1)
  1           33          12      10      10-(12+13+13+1)
  1           33          13      10      10-(13+13+1)
  1            3          13      10      10-(13+1
  1           44          1       10      10-(1)
  1            0          3       10       0
  1            0          0       0        0
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We can use `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df1 %>% 
    group_by(Pupil) %>% 
    mutate(points = replace(points, tail(which(participation == 0), 1), 0),
     bonus = bonus *(bonus != 0 & points != 0),
     Sum = (points - (accumulate_right(bonus*(participation != 0), 
             `+`)))* (participation !=0))
# A tibble: 14 x 5
# Groups:   Pupil [2]
#   Pupil participation bonus points   Sum
#   <int>         <int> <int>  <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     2            55     6     10   -23
# 2     2            33     3     10   -17
# 3     2            88     9     10   -14
# 4     2            44     8     10    -5
# 5     2            44     0     10     3
# 6     2            66     7     10     3
# 7     2             0     0      0     0
# 8     1            22    11     10   -40
# 9     1            33    12     10   -29
#10     1            33    13     10   -17
#11     1             3    13     10    -4
#12     1            44     1     10     9
#13     1             0     3     10     0
#14     1             0     0      0     0
```

Comment: Unfortunatly this data is just to illustrate and I can not use that code on my own data. I get values starting with -271748...

Comment: @fReezMA  This code is also for illustration of the problem mentioned in the example

Comment: I understand but it should work because I just changed the name of the values but at the end it is the same frame :(

Comment: @fReezMA  You need to assign the output to the original object i.e. `df1 <- df1 %>% group_by...`

Comment: So, I think my example was not enough to show you the real problem here. My frame can have multiple times the same pupil and multiple times the participation value == 0. So, I need to iterate through the list from the current row till i find participation == 0. after the participation row I can get the same pupil with random distritution of points  and there is somewhere again the participation == 0.. This can happen x times...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a base R split-apply-combine approach:

```
unsplit(lapply(split(df, df$Pupil), function(x) {
  idx <- rev(seq_len(max(which(cumsum(x$participation == 0) == 0))))
  x[idx, 'sum'] <- x[idx, 'points'] - cumsum(x[idx, 'bonus'])
  x[is.na(x$sum), 'sum'] <- 0
  x
}), df$Pupil)

   Pupil participation bonus points sum
1      2            55     6     10 -23
2      2            33     3     10 -17
3      2            88     9     10 -14
4      2            44     8     10  -5
5      2            44     0     10   3
6      2            66     7     10   3
7      2             0    11     10   0
8      1            22    12     10 -40
9      1            33    13     10 -28
10     1            33    13     10 -15
11     1             3    11     10  -2
12     1            44     1     10   9
13     1             0     3     10   0
14     1             0     0     10   0
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution.

```
df  =read.table(text="Pupil   participation   bonus   points
  2           55          6       10
  2           33          3       10
  2           88          9       10
  2           44          8       10
  2           44          0       10
  2           66          7       10
  2            0          0       10
  1           22          11      10
  1           33          12      10
  1           33          13      10
  1            3          13      10
  1           44          1       10
  1            0          3       10
  1            0          0       10",header=T)

library(data.table)
df = rbindlist(lapply(split(df,with(rle(df$participation==0),
                 rep(seq(length(values)),lengths))), 
                 function(x) {x$sum2=x$points-rev(cumsum(rev(x$bonus))); x}))
df$sum2[df$participation==0]=0
```

Output:

```
    Pupil participation bonus points                sum sum2
 1:     2            55     6     10   10-(6+3+9+8+0+7)  -23
 2:     2            33     3     10     10-(3+9+8+0+7)  -17
 3:     2            88     9     10       10-(9+8+0+7)  -14
 4:     2            44     8     10         10-(8+0+7)   -5
 5:     2            44     0     10           10-(0+7)    3
 6:     2            66     7     10             10-(7)    3
 7:     2             0     0      0                  0    0
 8:     1            22    11     10 10-(11+12+13+13+1)  -40
 9:     1            33    12     10    10-(12+13+13+1)  -29
10:     1            33    13     10       10-(13+13+1)  -17
11:     1             3    13     10           10-(13+1   -4
12:     1            44     1     10             10-(1)    9
13:     1             0     3     10                  0    0
14:     1             0     0      0                  0    0
```